# How to fix having too click twice on View report in ssrs

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012

Occasionally you have to click on view report twice before it will start to load.  There is no indication the query is started

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b0b04716-a4c2-4606-95cc-03ce84734d82/ssrs-2012-requires-clicking-view-report-button-twice?forum=sqlreportingservices   I wonder if initializing the date parameter could be causing the report not to query

Comment: Quote:  Some of our viewers have reported similar issue.  This usually occurs when they have selected multi-value parameters and then click "Apply" (or "View Report" in our older SharePoint environment) without clicking away first.  In other words, the first time they click "Apply", SSRS has only processed their selected parameters (as if they clicked anywhere else to accept the parameter selections).  Therefore the 2nd time they click "Apply", they are actually clicking the "Apply" button for the first time.  I do have a multi-select parameter

Comment: I can recreate the problem.   Type in a new date and then immediately press "View Report".  The focus somehow interferes with the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution requires you after typing in the date too tab out of the field then mouse click "View Report"